# How can I hide fields in an AcroForm?

Tags: itext

I am trying to execute following code to hide a field

```
    fields.SetFieldProperty("numberOfPages","setfflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_INVISIBLE, null );
 or 
    fields.SetFieldProperty("slash", "setfflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_HIDDEN, null);
```

I got the code from the Itext in Action book. I am  using Itextsharp 4.1.6 but get no result, no error thrown. What am I dıoing wrong? btw "setfflags" is from the book.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was asked 2 years ago but I couldnt find the answer anywhere online and hopefully this will help someone else who finds this post. Heres what I did to get this working in iTextSharp 4.1.6

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("[PATH_TO_PDF.pdf]"));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
    fields.SetFieldProperty("[FIELD_NAME]", "flags", PdfFormField.FLAGS_HIDDEN, null);
    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    stamper.Close();
}
```

I found the answer by looking through the iTextSharp source here:
https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6/blob/master/iTextSharp/text/pdf/AcroFields.cs#L1037

If you look at the methods comments, it shows you the valid property names and what they do.

Comment: `stamper.FormFlattening = true;` - this flattens the whole form. I doubt the OP actually wanted that...

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing field properties (`"setfflags"`) with annotation properties (`"setflags"`). Please read the [documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book/) and please don't use iTextSharp 4.1.6 because of [this reason](http://lowagie.com/itext2).

Comment: `because of this reason.` The link is broken, what is the reason?

Comment: @Maske It doesn't have a reason.